# How to create a directory, where users can delete only their own files, but one user can delete anyone's files?

Tags: rhel, chmod, acl, sticky-bit

Consider the following setup:

```
# two users in groups sales
useradd edwin
useradd santos
groupadd sales
usermod -aG sales edwin
usermod -aG sales santos

# two users in group account
useradd serene
useradd alex
groupadd account
usermod -aG account serene
usermod -aG account alex

# every group has its own directory with full access
mkdir -p ./groups/sales ./groups/account
cd ./groups
chown :account ./account
chown :sales ./sales
chmod g+rwx ./account ./sales
```

The task states:

> Users have permissions to delete only their own files, but alex is the general manager, so user alex has access to delete all users' files.

Now users should be able to only delete their own files, so I do:

```
chmod +t /groups/account /groups/sales
```

But now I have a problem. Alex is admin, and should be able to delete *anyone's*(!) files. So I do for example:

```
setfactl -a u:alex:rwx /groups/sales /groups/account
```

But this does not help:

```
[root@localhost groups]# getfacl sales/
# file: sales/
# owner: root
# group: sales
# flags: --t
user::rwx
user:alex:rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
[root@localhost groups]# sudo -u edwin touch sales/file
[root@localhost groups]# sudo -u alex rm -f sales/file
rm: cannot remove 'sales/file': Operation not permitted
```

Is it possible to apply sticky flag to all except one user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only missing part is that Alex should own the directory

```
chown alex ./groups/sales ./groups/account
```

Comment: It works... why? sticky bit does not apply to the owner of the directory? I see `setfacl` I did can be removed.

Comment: Correct - the owner of a directory can always delete items from it.